# How do I group similar type of skills together?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

Suppose that I have a file which has thousands of skills starting from A-Z. Now, I would like to create a model that can group similar skills together (example neural network and SVM can group together). I know that I can use NLP for this problem, but I'm not sure about the algorithm that I can use to get the best result.

I'm new to NLP so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If all you have is the name/word, then I see only two ways:

1. You can look at word similarity, basically by measuring how similar the spelling is. There are a number of possible metrics (e.g. [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)). This will probably not get you very far.
2. You can look at semantic similarity. You can use pre-trained [word embeddings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding) to map the words to a new vector space where you can calculate the distance between the word embeddings, e.g. with `word2vec` or other implementations. Alternatively, you can use a dictionary/corpus (e.g. https://www.nltk.org/index.html) that provides you a word taxonomy that allows you to compute semantic similarity between words via relationships like synonyms etc. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_similarity#Measures) for different approaches.

Comment: Can you show me some example?

Comment: what do you mean by pre-trained word embeddings?

Comment: if you are unfamiliar with these concepts it's probably best to review them first. if you have a specific question about them, you can open a new question. otherwise your question is too broad to be answered in this type of forum :-)